# How to start a rails server, wait for it to be up and the shut it down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, rake

I am trying to run some Javascript tests in a CI server. Thing is that this tests can only run if the Rails server is running. So I need to:

- start the rails server
- wait for it to be up
- run my JS runner
- shut down the server

Any idea on how to do this?

thanks